# Tile layout on the diagonal to minimize cutting

Tags: flooring, tile, ceramic-tile

I am tiling a bedroom floor with 20" tile on the diagonal.  Is there a way to layout the tile so as to minimize cutting?  I am fine with trying the layout in reality and making adjustments to it as needed.  I can also work with graph paper.

Comment: Personally, I don’t think that should be the goal. You really want your tiles centered on a central line down the longest dimension. Shifting an inch or two can be a good idea to prevent tiny pieces from being needed. Because you are doing diagonal, you are going to have to cut at least half of them anyway

Comment: I agree on a diagonal there will need to be more cuts and diagonal cuts can be tougher if you don’t have a tile saw or I tend to have a tougher time with small corner cuts chipping. With a wet saw it’s not so bad as long as the table is large enough for 20” tiles.

Comment: If the quantity of cuts is your biggest concern, don't do tile or pay someone to do it.  Planning is always a good idea and will reduce some waste, but no matter what pattern you pick, you will have a lot of cuts.  Putting your tile at a diagonal will only make this worse.  Buy a halfway decent wet saw and just get it done.

Comment: Rent or purchase a diamond wet-saw. If you are doing tile in the normal way, you will cut the entire perimeter of the room. If you are doing tile in the "but I don't wanna make cuts" way, you will cut at least half the perimeter of the room, and you might find that the walls you are trying not to cut along are not so stright and perpendicular as you might wish. Given that you are planning on the diagonal, just plan on cutting the whole perimeter, and get that wet-saw (the $20/day rental one may be a better deal than the $50 to buy it one, even if you need it for 3 days...)

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't. You'll want to follow a common strategy of either running a full tile or a joint down the center of the room so that the rows at the edges look appropriate. Snap one or two chalk lines on the floor as references, then snap one or two at 90 degrees to get your joint lines straight.

With a wet saw these types of cuts are not difficult nor time consuming. With a helper you can lay tile almost as fast as you can mark the cuts. Once you work out a strategy for measuring it's easy.

Answer (score 0):

with tiles aligned diagonally every edge tile will need to be cut. Arrange the layout for best look.

A 45 degree diagonal layout reduces wastage because the offcut can be used in the next place along (unless you are doing two-colour tiling, or have tiles with a directional pattern) it also hides crooked walls

Draw up the room outline to scale on transparent sheet and place it over a scale representation of the tile grid. Once it looks good staple it in place.

Try to avoid any layout that requires cutting the tips off tile corners, cutting one third to one half off is easier and looks better.

Comment: Saying not to cut a size is crazy if centered or not diagonal is way more cutting even if 2 walls are used with the tips touching 1/2 of the premier will need to be cut on those walls and possibly every tile on the other 2 walls, this should only be done when the design of the room hides the uneven wall cut.